# Is the interval [0, 1] in homotopy subset of real number?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am asking this question within the framework of my earlier posting *[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1167005/reversed-composition-proving-homotopy)*, for which I am grateful to @aes and @kobe for their generous help, thank you! Here are the question and its solution again for your convenience:

---

**QUESTION**: 
Given that $h_0, h_1: X \to Y$ and $k_0, k_1: Y \to Z$ are homotopic, prove that $k_0 \circ h_0$ and $k_1 \circ h_1$ are homotopic.

---

**SOLUTION**: 
(i) Here we are given that 
$$k_0 \circ h_0: X \to Z,\\
k_1 \circ h_1: X \to Z.$$

(ii) To prove that $k_0 \circ h_0 \simeq k_1 \circ h_1$, I claim that there exists a map $L: X \times I \to Z$, such that $L(x, 0) = k_0 \circ h_0 (x)$ as well as $L(x, 1) = k_1 \circ h_1(x)$, where $I = [0, 1]$ and $x \in X.$

(iii) And according to the response I got, that map $L$ would either be:

$$\begin{align}
L(x, t) &= k_t (h_t(x)), \quad t \in [0, 1], \text{ or }\tag{iiia}\\
\\
L(x, t) &= \tag{iiib}
\begin{cases}
k_0 (h_{2t} (x) ), &&\text{ for } t \in[0, \frac12]\\
k_{2t-1} (h_{1} (x) ), &&\text{ for } t \in [\frac12, 1].
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

---

Here are my burning questions: 
(1) Is the interval $I = [0, 1]$ subset of real number $\mathbb R, \mathbb Q$ or simply has to be read as either $0$ or $1$ only?

(2) If $I \subset \mathbb R$ then (iiia) and (iiib) will be in trouble since, for example, for $t = 0.3$ the $L (x, 0.3)$ will be a joker. I am pretty sure this is a fool's question but I don't know where the dummy is hiding.

(3) Do you think this boring, unimaginative map may count as an answer too, if $I \subset \mathbb R$?

$$L(x, t) =
\begin{cases}
k_0 \circ h_0(x), &t \in [0, \frac12)\\
k_1 \circ h_1(x), &t \in [\frac12, 1]
\end{cases}$$
Note the half-open interval $[0, \frac12)$ in the first piece.

(4) And finally, how about this plain vanilla $L(x, t)$, regardless of $I$ is a subset $\mathbb R$ or not:

$$L(x, t) = (1-t)k_0 \circ h_0(x) + (t)k_1 \circ h_1 (x)?$$

Thank you very much for your time and help.

---

**POST SCRIPT:** I pasted this image as an exhibit to my response to Carlos Laguillo's answer, see his answer below. The complete page can be found in this link [*here*](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~erin/topology/munkres.pdf). The question I posted above is Munkres' $\S$ 51 Exercise #1, the one I pasted below is $\S$ 51 Exercise #2. Many thanks to Carlos.

$$\text{~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~}$$

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me start off with a formal proof of the statement in question, then I'll get to your questions.

**Claim**: Let $h, h' : X \to Y$ and $k, k' : Y \to Z$. If $h \simeq h'$ and $k \simeq k'$, then $k \circ h \simeq k' \circ h'$.

**Proof**: Since $h \simeq h'$, there exists a continuous $H : X \times I \to Y$ with $H(s, 0) = h(s)$ and $H(s, 1) = h'(s)$. Define $h_t : X \to Y$ by $h_t(s) = H(s, t)$ and notice that
\begin{align*}
h_0(t) &= H(s, 0) = h(s) \\
h_1(s) &= H(s, 1) = h'(s).
\end{align*}

Since $k \simeq k'$, there exists a continuous $K : Y \times I \to X$ with $K(s, 0) = k(s)$ and $K(s, 1) = k'(s)$. Define $k_t : Y \to Z$ by $k_t(s) = K(s, t)$ and notice that
\begin{align*}
k_0(s) &= K(s, 0) = k(s) \\
k_1(s) &= K(s, 1) = k'(s)
\end{align*}

Define $L : X \times I \to Z$ by $$L(s, t) = \begin{cases} k_0\big(h_{2t}(s) \big) & 0 \leq t \leq 1/2 \\ k_{2t - 1} \big( h_1(s) \big) & 1/2 \leq t \leq 1.\end{cases}$$ Observe that
\begin{align*}
L(s, 0) &= k_0 \big( h_0(s) \big) = k \circ h(s) \\
L(s, 1) &= k_1 \big( h_1(s) \big) = k' \circ h' (s).
\end{align*}
Now notice that $ k_0\big(h_{2t}(s) \big)$ and $ k_{2t - 1} \big( h_1(s) \big)$ are continuous on $[0, 1/2]$ and $[1/2, 1]$, respectively, since the composition of continuous functions is continuous. Moreover they both agree at $t = 1/2$. By the **pasting lemma**, we can conclude that $L$ is continuous and hence the desired homotopy.

---

Let's start with looking at your two possible definitions of $L$. The problem with (iiia) is: how do you show it's continuous? Obviously $L(s, 0) = k \circ h(s)$ and $L(s, 1) = k' \circ h'(s)$, but how do you get continuity? You have two functions in two variables both changing at the same time which may cause you to work more to show continuity.

This is why you use (iiib). The continuity follows from the fact that we are composing a function in one variable with a function in two variables, for instance $k_0 \circ h_{2t}(s)$; the $k_0$ is fixed, unlike $k_t \circ h_t$ where the $k_t$ is changing as $t$ changes. We break it up into pieces that are continuous (pieces we can easily show to be continuous) and then use the pasting lemma to show the entire function you've just defined is continuous.

**Edit**: Disregard these last two paragraphs. Both functions are continuous by the same reasoning: the composition of two continuous functions is continuous. As long as we've shown $k_t$ and $h_t$ are continuous in two variables, both your definitions of $L$ should work perfectly. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878200/show-that-composition-of-continuous-function-is-continuous-in-product-topology).

For (1), $[0, 1]$ is the closed set of all elements in $\mathbb R$ between $0$ and $1$, hence there are uncountably infinitely many.

For (2), you don't have any problems with $t = 0.3$. since $L$ is defined on $X \times I$ and $0.3 \in I$.

For (3), this is not well-defined as $t$ doesn't play a role at all and $L$ must be defined on $X \times I$, not just $X \times \{0, 1\}$ (by definition of homotopy).

For (4), the definition doesn't work because scalar multiplication is not necessarily defined, but also, you're not given that the space is convex, so even if scalar multiplication were defined, the function may not be well defined if it were not convex.

Comment: I haven't seen you crusading in a bit.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm crusading too much; I'm afraid you guys are upvoting me too much and eventually it'll trigger a serial upvoting bot and undo all of it :P

Comment: That is risk one takes when they ride with King Arthur on noble causes.

Comment: @RobertCardona : I am always grateful whenever you are pitching in. I have up-voted and green check-marked yours!

Comment: @RobertCardona : (3) I think now I understand why this invention of mine $$L(x, t) =
\begin{cases}
k_0 \circ h_0(x), &t \in [0, \frac12)\\
k_1 \circ h_1(x), &t \in [\frac12, 1]
\end{cases}$$ does not work. It doesn't because as you said, "$t$ does not play a role here." Thank you! Your one phrase solves it all!

Comment: @RobertCardona : (2) I agree when you said that $t=0.3$ is possible since $L$ is defined when $t=0.3$. However, when it comes to pluging-in $t$ into subscript of $k$ and $h$, I have to stick to $t = \{0, 1\}$, for otherwise this will happen: $$L(x, t) = 
\begin{cases}
k_0 (h_{(0.6)} (x) ), \text{ for } &t \in[0, \frac12]\\
k_{(-0.4)} (h_{1} (x) ), \text{ for } &t \in [\frac12, 1].
\end{cases}$$which does not make sense. Am I correct? Thank you again.

Comment: It makes sense: $$L(s, 0.3) = k_0(h_{0.6}(s)) = k_0(H(s, 0.6)) = K(H(s, 0.6), 0) = k(H(s, 0.6))$$ which is okay! The key is how we defined $h_t(s)$ and $k_t(s)$. Oh and you only pick one of the two depending on whether $t \in [0, 1/2]$ or $t \in [1/2, 1]$, in this case, we pick the top one.

Comment: Aha, here you go again, another light bulb get lit! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would have left this as a comment, but I haven't enough reputation (I'm new here).

I think this is a problem on notation. In order to make this has sense and be correct we must understand $k_{t}$ as $H_{k}(x,t)$ where $H_{k}(x,t)$ is the homotopy between $k_{0}$ and $k_{1}$, and similarly for $h_{t}$. Then both answers (iiia) and (iiib) are correct.

Answering your questions:

(1) $I\subset \Bbb{R}$, we can think on it as the parameter that determines the **continuous** deformation from one map to another.

(2)This is the notation problem I mentioned above.

(3)No, that map doesn't need to be continuous on $t$. In fact, it will be continuous iff $k_{0}\circ h_{0}=k_{1}\circ h_{1}$.

(4)You were answered about this one in the other post, you can't multiply in general topological spaces, it may not make any sense.

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand your response to (1) and (2). Basically you said that it is indeed $I \subset \mathbb R$, but $t$ can not be literally assigned any real numbers for the purpose of subscript, therefore $t = 0.3$ is not possible. Please correct me if I am wrong again. Thanks again.

Comment: On your response to (3), if I understand you correctly, you said that this boring map, $$L(x, t) =
\begin{cases}
k_0 \circ h_0(x), &t \in [0, \frac12)\\
k_1 \circ h_1(x), &t \in [\frac12, 1]
\end{cases}$$ is not a valid answer, since $t$ is continuous? Mind if you elaborate a little bit more? Thanks again.

Comment: On your response to (4), I remember that I can't multiply general topological spaces with scalar, does this mean that a solution that I saw from website, see the exhibit in my posting's Post Script above, is wrong? (I posted the image as Post Script to my question because this comment does not take image.) Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: @A.Magnus just because that argument wouldn't work in a *general* topological space doesn't mean it NEVER works. In the example given the functions map into the interval $[0,1]$ and you can multiply by $t$ in that space in the sense of taking a convex combination.

Comment: In (1) and (2) I said $I\subset \Bbb{R}$, and it can be any real number on this interval, but must be understood as $k_{0.3}(x)=H_{k}(x,0.3)$.

In (3) what I said is that $L(x,t)$ is NOT continuous on $t$ in general, so it's not a valid homotopy.
Think on the functions $k_{i}\circ h_{i}$ as points in some space, then you are mapping half of the interval to one point and the other half to the other point.

To the POST SCRIPT, in this case you are multiplying on $\Bbb{R}$, not in a general topological space, as @JHance has told you

Comment: @JHance : Thank you! I think now I understand the nuance that $$k_0 \circ h_0 : X \to Z$$ is NOT multiply-able by scalar because it is a map from a topological space $X$ to another topological space $Z$, but $$\varphi: X \to I$$ is multiply-able because it is a map from topological space $X$ to an interval $I \subset \mathbb R$. Feel very free to correct me again and thank you again for clarification.

Comment: @CarlosLaguillo : Thank you again! On your counter-response to (1) and (2), don't you think there is a typo? You wrote "In (1) and (2) I said $I \subset \mathbb R$, and it can be any real number on this interval, but must be understood as $k_{0.3}(x)=H_{k}(x,0.3)$." Instead, shouldn't it be "... but must NOT be understood as $k_{0.3}(x)=H_{k}(x,0.3)$"? Thanks again!

Comment: @CarlosLaguillo : On your counter-response to (3), you wrote that "In (3) what I said is that $L(x,t)$ is NOT continuous on $t$ in general, so it's not a valid homotopy." But don't you think that $t$ does not have any gap here in $$t \in [0, \frac12) \cup [\frac12, 1],$$ where $[0, \frac12)$ is half-open? PS. Please do not take this one as doubting your response, I am either "curious to death" or "as curious as a cat." :-)

Comment: @ A.Magnus No, there is no typo, $k_{t_{0}}(x)$ must be understood as the image of the Homotopy between $k_{0}$ and $k_{1}$ at $(x,t_{0})$.

Comment: @A.Magnus And no, there is no gap in the union of those intervals, but that doesn't mean anything about $L(x,t)$.
I can define $f(t)= \left\{\begin{array}{cc}0 & if \ t\in [0,1/2) \\ 1 & if \ t\in[1/2,1] \end{array}\right.$ and $f$ is not continuous, obviously.
Furthermore, you are never using that $k_{0}$ and $k_{1}$ are homotopic, either with $h_{0}$ and $h_{1}$, this should be a clue that there is something wrong.